# why does the following code compile

Tags: c++, linker

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo {
void Bar( void ) const ;
};
int main()
{
  Foo f;
  cout<<sizeof(f)<<endl;
}
```

I ran this on g++,it did not give me any compilation error. Also, it executed giving o/p 1 which is correct. But I was expecting, error during linking. Is this compiler dependent?

Comment: Why did you expect a linker error?

Comment: Maybe because `Foo::Bar` is undefined.

Comment: @filmor And do you see any place where it is used (i. e. called or its address is taken)?

Comment: I would care more about the return...

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't say that I expect a linker error ;)

Comment: @Yn5an3 In the special case of the `main` function `return 0;` at the end is implicit.

Comment: @filmor Whoops. Sorry, I missed you are **not** OP. I should go to bed already, perhaps.

Comment: @filmor Thanks, first time I hear of this. I suppose I'm used to the C way of doing things. This question ilustrates perfectly 2 of the maaaany reasons why I believe C++ is not a "concise and practical" languaje. There are rules, exceptions, rules to the exceptions, exceptions to the rules and exceptions to the exceptions. I don't intend to start a discussion about it, but I believe it's just plain wrong, both the implicit return and the lack of a compilation error.

Comment: @Yn5an3 The implicit return of 0 is also part of C99.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can only imagine that you expected to get an error as `Foo::Bar` is not defined. The One Definition Rule in the standard requires only that *used* elements are defined. In your particular case, nothing in your program *uses* `Foo::Bar`, so the program does not need that definition.

Comment: I like your answer better than mine.

Comment: yes... calling Bar() does give error. But I was unaware about the dependency. Moreover, is it in the standard?

Answer (score 3):

This will link because there are no outstanding references to Foo::Bar, and there for its definition is not required. Had you actually tried to make a call such as f.bar() it would have given you the error.

Answer (score 3):

There is no linker error, because all dependencies are resolved.

As soon as you call the method `Bar()` and don't define it, you will get a linker error. Because then you reference `Bar()` and the linker cannot resolve it.